# Why does £ turn to A using xhtml and css

Tags: xhtml

I have noticed when i put a £ sign in it turns out to be a A when i look at my website in firefox. Do you know the reason why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Mandatory reading: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: To get an answer, please provide much more detail about your web site, and especially the encoding it uses. Also, are you sure you get an "A" for the pound sign? No accents or anything?

Answer (score 3):

it sounds like you've got a page encoded in UTF-8, but being displayed as Latin-1 - make sure the meta tags and/or server headers tell browser what encoding the page uses.

In an XHTML file, you need to declare the encoding in the initial XML tag, and for maximum compatibility, include a meta tag also

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
    ...
  </head>
```

Bobince suggests in a comment that for maximum backwards compatibility you do something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    ...
  </head>
```

If you're curious why you get strange letters, here's the likely explanation...

- The pound sign is Unicode character [U+00A3](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a3/index.htm)
- This is encoded in UTF-8 as the two byte sequence C2 A3
- if you interpreted that as Latin-1, you'd get Ã£

Comment: You don't need the XML Declaration (XHTML files parsed as XML rather than HTML are UTF-8 by default), and you shouldn't include it as it will trip IE6 into Quirks Mode. If you are serving the file as `text/html` as most people do for IE compatility, the `Content-Type` meta should match that.